# Amzi Prolog Tokenize

Tags: string, prolog, tokenize

I would want to read a file and store the words in every line as a list. This is my code:

```
main :-
open('sample.txt', read, Str),
read_file(Str,Lines),
close(Str),
write(Lines), nl.

read_file(Stream,[]) :-
at_end_of_stream(Stream).

append1([H|T],Old_list,New_list):-
New_List = [H|Old_list],
write(New_List),
append1(T,New_List,New_list).

read_file(Stream,[X|L]) :-
\+ at_end_of_stream(Stream),
read(Stream,X),
write(X),
append1(X,[],New_List),
read_file(Stream,L).
```

I realise that X is a term here but I am not able to get my program working.

```
Input : 'Australia', 'Singapore','23','34','Mon/Tue'.
Output : New_List=[Australia,Singapore,23,34,Mon/Tue].
```

I am using Amzi prolog btw!

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Your example suggests you are willing to quite a bit of formatting on the input side of things.  Conceivably if the input is as "nice" as you show, all that would be required (to get the desired list, is to input the given line as one string, remove the terminating period, and slap opening and closing square brackets around it.  The resulting string would be parsed by Amzi's predicate **string_term** as a list with the desired number of items.  The approach outlined in my Answer was intended to be a more robust and generalizable way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

The ISO predicate **read/2** inputs Prolog terms and requires the input to be terminated by a period.  You can try this interactively from the query prompt.

But likely what you want is not to read Prolog terms but rather to read an entire input line as a string and then tokenize that into "words" that are items in a list.

For this purpose Amzi! Prolog has several non-ISO predicates that could be useful.  See the [documentation here for **read_string/2**](http://www.amzi.com/manuals/amzi/pro/ref_io.htm#readstringStringreadstringIDSt), and see also the [documentation for **string_split/3**](http://www.amzi.com/manuals/amzi/pro/ref_text.htm#stringsplit) and [for **string_tokens/3**](http://www.amzi.com/manuals/amzi/pro/ref_text.htm#stringtokens).

One or the other of these latter two predicates is apt to be more useful, depending on what you want to do about whitespace and punctuation in your lists of "words".